# Table cell widths not working how I expected

Tags: css, css-tables

I have an order list, like this:

```
    <div class="content-tabs fixed-tabs">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a>Terms of Use</a></li>
            <li><a>Privacy Policy long long description</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to do things:

1 Maintain equal size tabs; and 2 constraint the maximum size of each tab

Please excuse the code - I'm currently experimenting. Here are the main 2 lines - as you can see I'm using a table to make cell alignment work.

```
.tabs {
    display: table;
}

.tabs li
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Below is the stuff I'm currently working with. This almost does what I want.

Output - notice extra padding on both tabs:

[image]

Correct output on single text line - notice lack of padding on widest tab

[image]
Both tabs are equal
The max width is set to 26.4rem in the code below - this is respected

However there is on niggle. When the text reaches the max width and wraps in the case of a long description, the width remains at 26.4rem, which is not necessarily correct. The reason it isn't is because having wrapped, the words on line 1 are typically then less than 26.4rem - their width could be 25rem, 24rem or whatever, so there is some extra padding either side.

What I need to know is can I make these table-cells shrink-wrap when text is wrapped, but still give them a maximum width?

```
.tabs {
    display: table;
}

.tabs li
{
    display:table-cell;
    height:4.8rem;
    min-width:16rem;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:26.4rem;
}

.tabs li a
{
        display:block;
        max-height:2.8rem;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to show the compiled CSS please.

Comment: The code has been edited and should now represent compiled CSS

Comment: @JohnOhara is the number of table cells known?

Comment: @JohnOhara ok, if only two of them, take a look of - http://jsfiddle.net/9qp3q0n2/ Let me know if that works,  or you need further tweaks.

Comment: Yep, the percentage on the cell works - thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you only have 2 table cells. Use a percentage `width:50%` on the cell should make it work.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9qp3q0n2/)**

```css
.tabs {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tabs li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a>Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a>Privacy Policy long long description</a></li>
</ul>

<br/><br/>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a>Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a>Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul>
```